# Is there an easier way to turn wifi on and off on iOS?

Tags: ios, wifi, settings

I realize that there are no shortcuts specifically for the Settings program on iOS.  With that in mind, perhaps there's another way to do what I'd like.

I live in the boonies, where the only effective internet I can get is through satellite.  This creates issues with my iPhone.  For instance, if I'm working on the lot and have wifi on and I'm listening to streaming, when I leave range, the stream stops and has to restart, which takes time.  The same happens when I walk back in range.  Also, I have unlimited bandwidth on my wireless plan and a cap on my satellite data.

Whenever I pick up my phone before going out of the house, I turn of wifi to avoid issues like the one above.  But when I come home, I need to turn wifi on so my photos will update and for other reasons.

It's not a terrible thing to go through, but it's several steps.  Is there any way to add an icon to the homescreen that turns wifi on and off?  Or any other easy shortcut to do this?

Comment: Did to try WiFi toggle in the Control Center? Also you can ask Siri to turn WIFI On and Off. I do that.

Comment: I am never sure just what I can and cannot ask Siri to do.  Is that just, "Wifi on," and "Wifi off?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't specify the model of iPhone you have, but the Control Centre is definitely the easiest way to toggle many functions on/off.

Typically, to access Control Centre you would swipe up from the bottom of the screen. If you have an iPhone X you need to **swipe down from the top right of the screen** instead.

You can configure the Control Centre by going to Settings > Control Centre. If you're on iOS 11 you have a lot more options available to you and can even select what functions you want available from the Control Centre.

Below is a screenshot of how I currently have my Control Centre configured:

[image]

As you can see, by accessing the Control Centre you can instantly tap on the Wi-Fi toggle to switch it on/off. The Control Centre also give you fast access to Bluetooth, Airplane Mode, etc.

Comment: Note that using Control Center to 'turn off' Bluetooth only disables it until the next day, when Bluetooth will turn itself back on. To turn off Bluetooth until _you_ want it back on requires one to go to `Settings > Bluetooth` and slide the switch manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Siri to turn Wi-Fi on and off:

[image]